# SQL Equivalent of RoundUp in Excel

Tags: sql, rounding

I am trying to round up 0.04268480693845 to 0.0428. Using the RoundUp formula in Excel achieves this but how can this be achieved in SQL?

I have tried using the below.

```
DECLARE @mynumber float = 0.04268480693845

SELECT  @mynumber AS MyNumber,
        ROUND(@mynumber,4) AS Round,
        CEILING(@mynumber) AS Ceiling,
        CEILING(@mynumber * 10000) / 10000 AS CeilingAdjusted,
        ROUND(CEILING(@mynumber * 10000) / 10000,4) AS CeilingRound
```

Results:

MyNumber = 0.04268480693845

Round = 0.0427

Ceiling = 1

CeilingAdjusted = 0.0427

CeilingRound = 0.0427

Comment: How are you getting that number to round up to 0.0428 in excel? `roundup(0.04268480693845,4) = 0.0427` in excel.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?